# How to create an admin account after my admin account got deleted

Tags: login, users, administration

My admin account has been deleted.

This was because I had to use the dell recovery after a problem after one of the updates provided by Ubuntu.

Now I only have the guest account.

How do I go about creating a admin account for my Ubuntu system?.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

First add a user name through this command

`adduser <username>`

You can then add a user to the sudo group with with the command:

`sudo adduser <username> sudo`

*Note that versions of Ubuntu until 11.10 will use admin as group instead of sudo*

Comment: It is not working. The reply is besh: username: No such file or directory